# Cant sort correctly when use GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mariadb

I Have two tables:

1. Products (id, product_name, option)
2. Prices (id, product_id, price, shop, available)

Each product can have several prices that each shop enters.

I want select products and sort them by price(lowest price) low to high.

But this code deos not work correctly:

```
Select
product_name,
Prices.price 
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.product_id=Products.id 
                AND Prices.available="yes"
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY Prices.price
LIMIT 0,10
```

The above code at first Group products by name then sort them by price
And its my problem.

**I dont want to show one product a few times**

Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: When a product has multiple prices which price do you want to use, in order to sort it? The cheapest one, the most expensive one, the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You only need an aggregation function in the `ORDER BY`.  However, I would also advise you to use table aliases, an `INNER JOIN`, and single quotes for the string constant:

```
SELECT p.product_name, MIN(pr.price)
FROM Products p INNER JOIN
     Prices pr
     ON pr.product_id = p.id 
        pr.available = 'yes'
GROUP BY p.product_name
ORDER BY MIN(pr.price)
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select
product_name,
MIN(Prices.price) as mprice 
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.product_id=Products.id AND Prices.available="yes"
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY mprice
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you GROUP BY you wont get the different prices for the same product. You could check for the MAX value or count them using agregate functions but you wont get your results this way. Also, you should have an intermediary table since a product can be in defferent models with different prices. And I don't get why you use a name attribute. Why don't you just use the product ID? And do something like

```
SELECT products.product_name, prices.price
FROM products, prices
WHERE products.ID = prices.product_ID;
ORDER BY prices.price ASC
```